# Wicket 6 - Custom JQuery-plugin causes StalePageException

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, wicket, wicket-6

I'm using Wicket 6 for an application and wanted to create a JQuery-plugin which keeps track of a Users' activity.

The idea is to refresh the http session once in a while and if the User has been idle for more than x minutes, initiate a logout/redirection (done serverside).
All this with the help of Ajax.

Now, this is the first time I have ever worked with JQuery (or JS for that matter) so below is the result of 3 hours worth of tutorialspoint.

```js
idleTimer = null;
idleWait = 12000;
var lastUserInteraction;
var lastServerInteraction;
(function($) {

  $(document).ready(function() {

    startTimer();

    $(document).bind("keypress click", function() {
      lastUserInteraction = Date.now();
      lastServerInteraction = new Date(document.lastModified).getTime();

      if ((lastServerInteraction - lastUserInteraction) < 8000) {
        restartTimer();
      }
    });

  });

  function startTimer() {

    window.console && console.log("TIMER STARTAD, " + idleWait + " millisekunder kvar");
    idleTimer = setTimeout(function() {

      window.location.reload(true);

    }, idleWait);

  }

  function restartTimer() {

    clearTimeout(idleTimer);
    window.console && console.log("RESTARTING TIMER");
    heartBeat();
    startTimer();
  }

  function heartBeat() {

    $.ajax({
      url: window.location.href,
      type: "HEAD",
      timeout: 1000,
      statusCode: {
        200: function(response) {
          console.log('Working!');
        },
        400: function(response) {
          console.log('Not working!');
        },
        0: function(response) {
          console.log('Not working!');
        }
      }
    });
  }
})(jQuery)
```

This code "works" in the sense that it updates the timer and the http-session depending on the users activity (timeout is set to 10 seconds on the server and 12 seconds here in the client). It also logs out and redirects the user to the loginpage if the session does time out.

However whenever I try to make any sort of callback through any of my components (textfield, button etc). it results in a StalePageException.

Any suggestions? My skin is thick so dont hold back on the critique

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
$.ajax({
  url: window.location.href,
  ...});
```

`StalePageException` is being thrown by Wicket when the use tries to use a page **instance** that has been rendered at least one more time since the rendering of the current page.

The urls produced by Wicket look like: `some/path?11-22.path~to~component.33`.

Here `11` is the page id. It is unique identifier of a page instance for the current http session.

`22` is the page render count. It shows how many times this particular page instance has been rendered.

`33` is the index of component's behavior. It is not interesting for this problem.

So `22` is what causes the problem. When the page is rendered by Wicket the renderCount value is `X`. Then when you make the Ajax call to the url of the current page instance Wicket will increment the renderCount at the server side to `X+1`. Later when you click on any link/button in the page Wicket will make a request with `X` and it will fail the comparison at the server side against `X+1` and Wicket will throw PageStaleException.

You have several options to avoid this:

- mount a resource (see Application.mountResourceReference). This is similar to plain Servlet. The benefits are that the resources/servlets are stateless and there won't be any kind of response construction. All you need is to send a simple GET request (even HEAD is fine) to refresh the http session
- make a request to `/some/page` (without the query string, `?11`). This will create a new instance of this page and thus won't affect the current instance. But it will do all the work needed to render this page, like hitting database, etc.

Comment: So the URL for the request will be something like "window.location.pathname + '/path/to/resource' " ? I took a slight try at the first suggestion and it works, however it also creates new instances of the page every time the request fires. Wicket is being used here on top of Spring Boot and I just saw that my predecessors use a pom-file to include the resources. Two resource tags with two different targetPath-tags; "public" and "org/apache/wicket". All I did then was to add a a script-tag in the header-section with my jquery-plugin. Isn't this the same as mounting it programmatically?

Comment: The best would be to ask Wicket to create the url to the resource for you: `RequestCycle#urlFor(ResourceReference)` and pass it to the JS code. But you can just hardcode it in the JS code as well, `'/path/to/resource'` should be fine. I do not understand the part with targetPath-tags.