How to prevent StalePageException when using AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior triggered from other javascript components
I have a page that is mostly wicket, but there's a third party grid component on the page. It loads it's data via a URL I give it to an AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.  We also invoke a 2nd AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior from an event listener tied to row selections on the grid. This url is placed in a hidden and invoked as they check that row.
Problem is that it's not working. We've done similar things in other apps, and I'm failing to see what is different. What seems to be happening, is that when we click, Wicket is issuing a StalePageException, and sending a redirect to the client which then reloads the page, wiping out the selections. The following error is in the log:
org.apache.wicket.core.request.mapper.StalePageException: A request to page '[Page class = my.package.queue.modules.ReportQueue, id = 3, render count = 1]' has been made with stale 'renderCount'. The page will be re-rendered.

The problem being that I don't see what I'm doing differently from other places where this strategy works. It seems like the URL I get from getCallbackUrl() has the render count in it, and I presume that when other ajax events are invoked, Wicket probably expects an updated one.  Since I need to push these out at page load, and don't know what order they'll come back, it's not really practical for me to keep asking for a new Url.  How can I get it to ignore the render count on these ajax calls?
The behavior definition in java:
        behaviorDisable = new AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior() {
            protected void respond(final AjaxRequestTarget target) {    
                //code redacted, but control never arrives here so it doesn't matter.
            }   
        };
        
        add(behaviorDisable);
        String callback = String.valueOf((behaviorDisable.getCallbackUrl()));
        hiddenfield = new HiddenField("callBackUrl", new Model(callback));
        add(hiddenfield);

And in the javascript, I've gone through many iterations with parameters and whatnot, but they all do the same.  Here's the current one:
        Wicket.Ajax.get({
            "u" :document.getElementById('callBackUrl').value
        });

We're using jQuery 3.6.3 with wicket 6.
Before you recommend upgrading, yes, we know it's old. Our client is governmental and doesn't like to upgrade unless there's a major security finding or some other external force compelling them. We can't get permission to upgrade. There's a 'modernization' effort scheduled, but it keeps getting pushed back as literally everything is a higher priority.

I have since found this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51206917/wicket-6-custom-jquery-plugin-causes-stalepageexception) which is a similar problem to mine, but the solutions offered by Martin G I think don't apply because I'm trying to affect the state of components within the page.  So I don't think I can mount a resource or invoke a new page instance.  I need wicket it IGNORE the rendercount and let my event happen.  At least, that's what I think I need.

Can you use a stateless ajax behavior for your use case ?

I was unaware of such a thing.  Is it an alternate class to AbstractAjaxBehavior?  I don't see a 'StatelessAjaxBehavior' or anything.  How would one go about this?  @martin-g

https://nightlies.apache.org/wicket/guide/10.x/single.html#_stateless_ajax_componentsbehaviors
